# Compare two groups to see if they have the same people and assign ID to similar groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to create a master "Household ID" for groups that have the same people in each household. For example, say I have a dataset with 4 people that are found in seven different households.

```
dt <- read.table(header=T, text='
        p_id    hh_id
        1   100
        2   100
        3   100

        1   200
        2   200
        3   200

        1   300
        2   300
        3   300
        4   300

        2   400
        3   400

        2   500
        3   500
        4   500

        2   600
        3   600

        2   700
        3   700
        4   700
             ')
```

I'd like to create a master household ID that identified households that had the same ID based on exactly who was in the household.

```
        p_id    hh_id   master_id
        1       100     1       
        2       100     1
        3       100     1
        1       200     1
        2       200     1
        3       200     1
        1       300     2
        2       300     2
        3       300     2
        4       300     2
        2       400     3
        3       400     3
        2       500     4
        3       500     4
        4       500     4
        2       600     3
        3       600     3
        2       700     4
        3       700     4
        4       700     4
```

BONUS: What would be the best way to add a weight to this ID calculation based on some criteria, like whether most of the "primary" people were in the other households? For example, if person 1 and 2 are adults, and 3 and 4 are children, how could we make keep a master `master_id` when 1 and 2 are together, but different when one of them is missing?

```
        p_id    hh_id   master_id   wt_m_id
        1       100     1           1       
        2       100     1           1
        3       100     1           1
        1       200     1           1
        2       200     1           1
        3       200     1           1
        1       300     2           1
        2       300     2           1
        3       300     2           1
        4       300     2           1
        2       400     3           2
        3       400     3           2
        2       500     4           2
        3       500     4           2
        4       500     4           2
        2       600     3           2
        3       600     3           2
        2       700     4           2
        3       700     4           2
        4       700     4           2
```

I tried the following code but it only create sequential numbers or was trying to get at something completely different.

```
dt %>% mutate(new_id = interaction(p_id, hh_id))
```

and

```
dt %>% mutate(ID = group_indices_(dt, .dots=c("p_id", "hh_id")))
```

Comment: My first response was going to be complete sarcasm ... but please don't just ask somebody to code this for you. Show some effort (and your code), please.

Comment: I hear you on this, but to be honest, I'm a at a complete loss on how to do this. I've tried the intersection function and the dplyr's group_indeces_ function but they didn't produce what I'd hoped. `dt %>% mutate(new_id = interaction(p_id, hh_id))` and `dt %>% mutate(ID = group_indices_(dt, .dots=c("p_id", "hh_id")))`

Comment: Tim, if you've tried that code and it doesn't work, *include that code and why it doesn't work* (in the question, not a comment please). Showing that goes a long way to show that you've put in effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea here, is that we can create a unique household ID by creating an ID column based off the combination of people

First, we need to group by `hh_id` because that determines which people share a household. Then we sort by `p_id`, because presumably, having `1, 2, 3` in a household is equivalent to having `2, 1, 3` in a household. Then we concatenate the `p_id`s within each group using `stringr::str_c`, with `collapse = ""`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

dt %>% group_by(hh_id) %>% 
  arrange(hh_id, p_id) %>% 
  mutate(HH_Group = str_c(p_id, collapse = ""))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   hh_id [7]
    p_id hh_id HH_Group
   <int> <int> <chr>   
 1     1   100 123     
 2     2   100 123     
 3     3   100 123     
 4     1   200 123     
 5     2   200 123     
 6     3   200 123     
 7     1   300 1234    
 8     2   300 1234
```

`HH_Group` now represents each group of people in the household. If you wanted to normalize `HH_Group` to a sequential integer, you could do:

```
dt$HH_Group <- as.numeric(as.factor(dt$HH_Group))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   hh_id [7]
    p_id hh_id HH_Group
   <int> <int>    <dbl>
 1     1   100        1
 2     2   100        1
 3     3   100        1
 4     1   200        1
 5     2   200        1
 6     3   200        1
 7     1   300        2
 8     2   300        2
```

Comment: Thanks Mako212, this is incredibly helpful and makes a ton of sense now. That's a great idea too to use grouped `as.numeric(as.factor())` to get sequential integers. Thank you so much!